# Escaping trouble - Blade Template in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

My view contains the following code

```
@foreach ($building as $maps)
    <div class="btn-group">
       <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" href="{{ URL::asset('floorPlans/$maps') }}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
          {{ $x }}
       </a>
    </div>
<?php $x++; ?>
@endforeach
```

Yet this is resulting in the follwoing HTML

```
<div class="btn-group">
   <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" href="http://facilities-lara.hslc.wisc.edu/floorPlans/$maps" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">2</a>
</div>
```

With **$maps** still being appended to URL instead of the value within $maps. Is it possible to retrieve the value *within* a blade template?

Thanks,
Otterman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything between the blade tags is just normal PHP. So you can simple concatenate the string and the variable:

```
{{ URL::asset('floorPlans/'.$maps) }}
```